# Statement closed with hibernate cause other queries error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, resultset

I am developing backend server with Java using spring 3.14 and hibernate 3.6.10 (and of course a lot of other libraries, but I suppose those are most important in that case). Server is used by several clients, one of them is android and due to mistake in android code (unnecessary multiple calls to backend one after another) I detected bug in my server which I can't solve wasting time for few days so far. So the problem is that when I run multiple DB queries (named queries to be exact) I got an error. What is really interesting the error varies! One time I get NPE on hibernate call "close connection" (stack trace 1), another I get "statement has been closed no further information" - stack 2. I saw few more, but all seemed to appear because statement had been released. To let You understand what I am doing to obtain the result I paste a code at the very bottom. Please also find pastes of my configuration below the stack traces.

- Stack trace 1 - http://pastebin.com/4CABYAYH
- Stack trace 2 - http://pastebin.com/PZ1R9Xxb

So to recap. Application fails when there are many connections to DB made asynchronously. After almost two days of thinking and trying I give up. Maybe somebody would help me, I will be grateful...

Anyway of course here comes all configuration and piece of code.

applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testSchema"
      p:username="train_together" p:password="..." p:initialSize="5" p:maxActive="10">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <entry key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.train"/>
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
         version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate" value="thread" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As I said problem appears with multiple queries run in the same time so I simply created new REST endpoint which runs two threads with very simple named query.

here is my rest method:

```
@GET
@Path("1")
public Response test1(@QueryParam("i") @DefaultValue("10") int iterations) {
    String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4);
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("    request consumed: " + key);
    System.out.println("*************************");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                    System.out.println("*************************");
                    System.out.println("\tThread: 1 " + key + " iteration:  " + (i+1));
                    userDao.getUsersOfTypeFromSportClub(UserType.CONTENDER, 1L);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println(Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e));
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i=0; i< iterations; i++) {
                    System.out.println("*************************");
                    System.out.println("\tThread: 2 " + key + " iteration:  " + (i+1));
                    userDao.getUsersOfTypeFromSportClub(UserType.CONTENDER, 1L);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println(Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e));
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

The UserDAO ovverides the base dao:

```
 public abstract class BaseDao<T> {

    protected EntityManager em;
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PersistenceUnit
    public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
        this.em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

P.S. the named query called by UserDao in my tests works properly.

Comment: And your dao is flawed... Don't inject the `EntityManagerFactory` and create an `EntityManager`. That is only usable once. Inject the `EntityManager` using `@PersistenceContext` and have proper tx management (your sample code doesn't have that, so your connections never return to the pool). Generally those errors are related to wrong (or no) transaction management, leading to connections leaks, leading to pool starvation, leading to an unusable application.

Comment: Also I assume that the thing in your persistence.xml is `hibernate.current_session_context` don't mess around with that as your setting is breaking proper spring integration.

Comment: @M.Deinum : 1. about `emf` and `em`: I was injecting `em` instead of `emf` via `@PersistenceContext` and I was facing the problem. So I started googling and I though that I have to provide `trasaction-type="JTA"` instead of `"RESOURCE_LOCAL"` and then I read that when you use JTA you should inject emf instead em so I tried this, but simply forgot to revert before posting code here. So with injecting `em` apporach it fails as well. What do You mean that transactions are wrongly configured? For update methods I use `@Transactional` but what for is transaction needed in case of read actions?

Comment: You still need proper tx setup for that, especially if you want spring to manage your resources... If you don't the connection stays open until it times out, instead of being returned to the pool when the transaction has ended.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thank You so far. I have to confess that I know very little about tx setup :( I will read about it and try to configure it properly. I will let You know if it helped :)